# How to redirect the user to another page after login using JavaScript Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, python, redirect, fetch, fastapi

Using the following JavaScript code, I make a request to obtain the firebase token, and then a `POST` request to my FastAPI backend, using the JavaScript [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method, in order to login the user. Then, in the backend, as can be seen below, I check whether or not the token is valid, and if so, return a redirect (i.e., `RedirectResponse`) to another webpage. The problem is that the redirect in the browser does not work, and the previous page remains.

```js
function loginGoogle() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth()
            //.currentUser.getToken(provider)
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then((result) => {
                /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
                var credential = result.credential;

                // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
                var token = credential.idToken;
            
                // The signed-in user info.
                var user = result.user;
                
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                // The email of the user's account used.
                var email = error.email;
                // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                var credential = error.credential;
                // ...
                
                });

        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
            console.log(idToken)

            const token = idToken;
            const headers = new Headers({
                    'x-auth-token': token
            });
            const request = new Request('http://localhost:8000/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: headers
            });
            fetch(request)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));

         
        })
```

The endpoint in the backend that returns the login page that contains the HTML code with the button and the `loginGoogle` function:

```
@router.get("/entrar")
def login(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("login.html", {"request": request})
```

I call this `POST` endpoint and then a redirect to `/1` which is a `GET` route, and with `status_code` being `303`, which is how @tiangolo specifies it in the doc to redirect from a `POST` to a `GET` route.

```
@router.post("/login")
async def login(x_auth_token: str = Header(None)):
    valid_token = auth.verify_id_token(x_auth_token)
   
    if valid_token:
        print("token validado")
        return RedirectResponse(url="/1", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
    else:
        return {"msg": "Token no recibido"}
```

This is the `GET` endpoint to which the user should be redirected, but it doesn't:

```
@app.get("/1")
def get_landing(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("landing.html", {"request": request})
```

Swagger screenshot of testing the `/login` endpoint:
[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code and details _as text_. Images have bad accessibility, requires the reader to switch back and forth, doesn't allow for copy and pasting the code or referencing details in an answer, and makes it impossible to search for any relevant details.

Comment: Done, sorry guys!

Comment: yes, is the same

Comment: INFO:     127.0.0.1:53670 - "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 303 See Other
INFO:     127.0.0.1:53670 - "GET /1 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK   can the error be that I am sending a post to a get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect the user back to the home page using FastAPI, after submitting an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70690454/how-to-redirect-the-user-back-to-the-home-page-using-fastapi-after-submitting-a)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804).

Comment: none of these answers solves my problem

Comment: actually the problem is that in the swagger if I do the redirect, but then in the browser does not, stays on the previous page.

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef I have updated the question, with an image of my swagger, passing the auth token if I do the redirect to the url I want, but when I do it through the browser does not do anything does not redirect me.

Comment: @Chris I have looked at the questions you passed me and none of them solve my error, and yes I am testing the api, using a basic html button that does onclick() on a function to get the google token from firebase and then does a fetch to my api, which after checking it should redirect. Maybe it has to do with the loading time, why does the google form have to load first to login and then do the redirect?

Comment: @Chris I don't know what code you mean by relevant, I actually have a post and I'm doing a redirect to a get, there's not much more code to look at, there's the part of the front end that sends the token but I don't think that code is relevant to this problem.

Comment: @Chris i updated the question. sorry for not knowing how to extend the problem, I am new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1 - Returning `RedirectResponse`

When using the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) function to make an HTTP request to a server that responds with a `RedirectResponse`, the redirect response will be [automatically followed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax:%7E:text=Automatically%20follow%20redirects.) on client side (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804)), as the `redirect` mode is set to `follow` in the `fetch()` function by default. This means that the user won't be redirected to the new URL, but rather `fetch()` will follow that redirection behind the scenes and return the response from the redirect URL. You might expected that setting `redirect` to `manual` instead would allow you to get the redirect URL (contained in the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) response header) and manually navigate to the new page, but this is not the case, as described [here](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/763).

However, you could still use the default `redirect` mode in the `fetch()` request, i.e., `follow` (no need to manually specify it, as it is already set by default—in the example below, it is manually defined for clarity purposes only), and then use [`Response.redirected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/redirected) to check whether or not the response is the result of a request that you made which was redirected. If so, you can use [`Response.url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url), which will return the *"final URL obtained **after** any redirects"*, and using JavaScript's [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href), you can redirect the user to the target URL (i.e., the redirect page).

Instead of `window.location.href`, one can also use [`window.location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). The difference from setting the `href` property value is that when using the `location.replace()` method, after navigating to the given URL, the current page will not be saved in session [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)—meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.

#### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')


@app.get('/')
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})

    
@app.post('/login')
async def login(data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    # perform some validation, using data.username and data.password
    credentials_valid = True
    
    if credentials_valid:
        return RedirectResponse(url='/welcome',status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
    else:
        return 'Validation failed'
 

@app.get('/welcome')
async def welcome():
    return 'You have been successfully redirected'
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
            document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default action
              var formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
              var data = new FormData(formElement);
              fetch('/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    redirect: 'follow',
                    body: data,
                 })
                 .then(res => {
                    if (res.redirected) {
                       window.location.href = res.url;  // or, location.replace(res.url); 
                       return;
                    } 
                    else
                       return res.text();
                 })
                 .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data;
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                 });
            });
         });
             
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="myForm">
         <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="user@mail.com"><br>
         <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="pa55w0rd"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
      </form>
      <div id="response"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Option 2 - Returning JSON response containing the redirect URL

Instead of returning a `RedirectResponse` from the server, you could have the server returning a normal JSON response with the URL included in the JSON object. On client side, you could check whether the JSON object returned from the server—as a result of the `fetch()` request—includes the `url` key, and if so, retrieve its value and redirect the user to the target URL, using JavaScript's `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace()`.

Alternatively, one could add the redirect URL to a custom [response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) on server side (see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994223/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804) on how to set a response header in FastAPI), and access it on client side, after posting the request using `fetch()`, as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers#examples) (Note that if you were doing a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request, you would have to set the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) response header on server side (see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804), as well as FastAPI's [`CORSMiddleware` documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware) on how to use the `expose_headers` argument), indicating that your custom response header, which includes the redirect URL, should be made available to JS scripts running in the browser, since only the [CORS-safelisted response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header) are exposed by default).

#### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status, Depends
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')


@app.get('/')
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})

    
@app.post('/login')
async def login(data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    # perform some validation, using data.username and data.password
    credentials_valid = True
    
    if credentials_valid:
        return {'url': '/welcome'}
    else:
        return 'Validation failed'
 

@app.get('/welcome')
async def welcome():
    return 'You have been successfully redirected'
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
            document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // Cancel the default action
              var formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
              var data = new FormData(formElement);
              fetch('/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data,
                 })
                 .then(res => res.json())
                 .then(data => {
                    if (data.url)
                       window.location.href = data.url; // or, location.replace(data.url);
                    else
                       document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = data;
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                 });
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="myForm">
         <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
         <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="user@mail.com"><br>
         <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="pa55w0rd"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
      </form>
      <div id="response"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Option 3 - Using HTML `<form>` in the frontend

If using a `fetch()` request is not a requirement for your project, you could instead use a normal HTML `<form>` and have the user click on the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) button to send the `POST` request to the server. In this way, using a `RedirectResponse` on server side (as demonstrated in Option 1) would result in having the user on client side automatically be redirected to the target URL, without any further action.

**Working examples** can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804).